# Which projects with open source you can see the use of advanced memory management?

Tags: c++, memory-management, open-source, project

I want to know what open source projects are used things like arena, allocators, overloading new and etc.
This refers to the C + + language.

Comment: [Boost Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [google perf tools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) and [jemalloc](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/). The last one is used in freebsd as default malloc implementation. So, every project that use any of this two use arenas, cause both use them internally. `new` operator in c++ is usually implemented with libc's `malloc` function.  Also, see [nginx http server sources](http://nginx.org/en/), it allocates memory pool for the session before the connection is created (but it's written in pure c). Apache has an [apr pools library](http://www.apachetutor.org/dev/pools).